# Extjs4 -how to generate the grid from the returned json?

Tags: extjs4

I have a form and a grid to submit a query,like this:

```
items:[  
{  
     fieldLabel: 'query the month',  
     xtype     : 'textfield',  
     name      : 'query_year_month',  
     id:   'query_year_month'  
} ],  

buttons:  {  
    text: 'submit',  
    formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid  
    disabled: false,
    handler: function() {
        //some code         
        }

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: //uncertain,
        region : 'south',
        pageSize: 15,

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'brokee/brokagequery/',
            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
            }
        },

        autoLoad: false    
});
```

I'd like to load data to a grid  after submiting the form.The return data is a json
structure,I don't want to define the static model bind to the store and neither the grid columns,because the data returned is uncertained.  The  store model and grid columns should be generated from the json data,
for example:  json: {'field1':data1, 'field2':data2}
the model should be generated like this:

```
Ext.define('somemodel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'field1', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'field2', type: 'string'}
               ]
});
```

In the official demo, the store and model are predefined, then call the store.load method to refresh the grid throuth the proxy.But how can I do that when the store and model need to be generated?

Answer (score 0):

When you have your json loaded, you can create store store/model like this.... use record .raw to extract values and :

```
Ext.create("Ext.data.JsonStore",{
    id:record.raw.storeID,
    model: Ext.define('App.dataGridModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [record.raw.id, record.raw.first]...
    })
...

});
```

the same with the grid etc..